# How do I show a property in the light DOM

Tags: html, polymer, shadow-dom

I'm expecting to see `hello` but I'm seeing `{{someVar}}`

```
<my-parent some-var="hello">
  <div>{{someVar}}</div>
</my-parent>
```

I am passing `some-var="{{someVar}}"` to `<content>`:

```
<dom-module id="my-parent>
  <template>
    <content some-var="{{someVar}}"></content>
  </template>

  <script> Polymer({is: "my-parent"}); </script>
</dom-module>
```

> I need this variable to be bound, such that if I embed another component, rather than a `<div>`, the embedded component can change the parent's property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little hard to explain.. but the only element that can see the `{{someVar}}` binding is the element that contains `my-parent`. The div is not physically moved inside of the content element, it's just 'projected' so it visually renders in that position. This is how native Shadow DOM works.

If you need to do something with your distributed children you'll probably want to use the effectiveChildNodes API https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#effective-children

Comment: thanks, really appreciate the help, its hard to research because docs are a little fragmented and lengthy sometimes, and 0.5 takes up a lot of stackoverflow. im a huge fan of the flexibility but have trouble with the context/scoping and interconnection of components

Answer (score 0):

In `some-child`, make sure the property definition has `notify: true`

```
properties: {
    locationHref: {
        type: String,
        notify: true
    }
}
```

See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#property-notification